# Is there any way to understand the output features of the word2vec?

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to understand what each dimension means in the output of word2vec.

For example if I make a decision tree with one hot encoded variables, I can tell exactly which category in a categorical variable is responsible for the split. If I use embeddings however, I can't explain the reason for these splits.

I am aware of the famous example of Embedding(King) - Embedding(Man) + Embedding(Woman) = Embedding(Queen). From this example, we can say that the characteristic of "royalty" has been understood.

I guess a way would be to cluster similar data points based on cosine similarity to get some context about what the output features are.

For example, if I get the nearest 3 neighbors of a data point to be "Kilometer", "Inch" and "Mile". I could infer that the "Length" is the could be responsible for the split in a decision tree. However, I was wondering if there was a another way.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, word embeddings are mostly generated in an unsupervised manner. Therefore, when it's seeded different attributes can actually be found. In fact some Word2Vec runs could possibly never pick up the attribute for royalty or length.

Furthermore, the attributes are somewhat meaningless in terms of their order. As long as the same attribute is found in the same place that is all that matters.

Based on this, Word Embeddings fundamentally need to be investigated to correlate it's items with what we would label things as. The fascinating question is are there items that do not correlate to concepts of ours but are still useful for word embedding.

Something that you may be interested is Semantic Ontologies and how they relate different semantic concepts.